# Which will produce faster fat loss results in a caloric deficit, myofibrillar or sarcoplasmic hypertrophy?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, workout-routines, bodybuilding, powerlifting

With all other things equal, such as a caloric deficit of about 15-20% TDEE, ~1-1.2g protein/lb. body weight, approximately the same amount of time spent in the gym, a solid routine, and no cardio, which will produce faster fat loss results:

1. myofibrillar hypertrophy (such as powerlifting), or
2. sarcoplasmic hypertrophy (such as bodybuilding)?

If it helps, I am pretty new to weightlifting, having started about 6 months ago. I was an athlete in my youth and a cardio addict for the past 10 years. My DEXA scan 6 months ago put me at 30% BF, but I don't think I look it with clothes on so I'm pretty skinny fat from cardio and disordered eating. I have been focusing on progressive overload (I have already lost fat in my belly, yay!) but I can't seem to decide on any one workout and I know I should. So far I really like all of it so the deciding factor would be results. Don't care about scale weight anymore (hooray!) just fat-be-gone. Thanks in advance!